# Adding rules to the tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, booktabs

How does one automatically add a `\bottomrule` at the end of a `tabularx` environment?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{#1}}%
  \toprule%
}{%
  \bottomrule%
  \end{tabular}%
}%

\newenvironment{mytabularx}[1]{%
  %\apptocmd\tabularx{\toprule}{}{\errmessage{Failed to patch tabularx}}
  % => Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\toprule): `c' used.

  \expanded{\noexpand\tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}}%
  \toprule
  % => works
}{%
  \endtabularx%
}%

\newenvironment{mytabularX}[1]{%
  %\pretocmd\TX@endtabularx{\bottomrule}{}{\errmessage{Failed to patch tabularx}}
  % => ./main.tex:59: Misplaced \noalign.
  % => \bottomrule ->\noalign
  % =>                        {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
  % => l.59 \begin{mytabularX}{Xcrl}
  %\preto\TX@endtabularx{\bottomrule}%
  % => ./main.tex:59: Misplaced \noalign. (same as above)

  \expanded{\noexpand\tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}}%
}{%
  %\bottomrule
  % => ./main.tex:61: Misplaced \noalign.
  % => \bottomrule ->\noalign
  % =>                        {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
  % => l.61 \end{mytabularX} (same error, different line)
  \endtabularx%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}{lcrl}
  this & is & my & table \\
\end{mytabular}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{mytabularx}{lcrX}
  this & is & my & table \\
\end{mytabularx}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{mytabularX}{Xcrl}
  this & is & my & table \\
\end{mytabularX}

\end{document}
```

The most frustrating part about this is that it works for adding at the beginning of the environment.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `tabularray` package, it can realize the separation of content and style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,colspec={Xcrl},hline{1,Z}={.08em},hline{2-Y}={.05em}}
\lipsum[1][1-5] & is & my & table \\
\lipsum[1][1-2] & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Add

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,colspec={Xcrl},hline{1,Z}={.08em}}
\lipsum[1][1-5] & is & my & table \\
\lipsum[1][1-2] & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,colspec={Xcrl},hline{Z}={.08em}}
\lipsum[1][1-5] & is & my & table \\
\lipsum[1][1-2] & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
this            & is & my & table \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the OP say they wanted a horizontal rule after *every* row? I may be wrong, but I thought the OP "merely" wanted automatic insertion of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` in the appropriate locations (as well as insertion of `{\textwidth}`).

Comment: @Mico I don't know if you are familiar with `tabularray`. `tabularray` is easy to control it. Just to change content of `hline` as shown in my example.

Comment: My question was not about the particulars of `tabularray`. It was about whether the result meets the OP's typographical needs and expectations.

Comment: @Mico I supplemented my answer. I think the key to OP is how to avoid inserting horizontal lines manually. Maybe my understanding of OP is wrong. Maybe OP is not trying to solve this problem. Then it's better to see which answer OP chooses.

Comment: Indeed, it would be helpful if the OP weighed in more information.

Answer (score 1):

For information, if you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (which accepts `X` columns in the style of `tabularx`), you can program directly an environment over the environment `{NiceTabular}` (because `{NiceTabular}` does not catch its body as does `{tabularx}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyTabularX}{m}
  {\begin{NiceTabular}{#1}
   \toprule
  }
  {\bottomrule
   \end{NiceTabular}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{MyTabularX}{lX}
some text & \lipsum[1] \\
some longer text & \lipsum[2] \\
\end{MyTabularX}

\end{document}
```

But there is a (small) drawback: you need several compilations (`nicematrix` writes informations on the `aux` file).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\preto\endarray{\bottomrule}`, which is a hook from the array package for tables in general. Scope appears to be limited to the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your objective is to define and work with an environment called `mytabularx`, which needs the following additions in order to make it work like a normal `tabularx` environment would:

- Automatically replace `\begin{mytabularx}{<col spec>}` with

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{<col spec>} \toprule
  ```

  i.e., supply the `{\textwidth}` argument and append `\toprule`. Put differently, you don't want to have supply these two "items" to the `mytabularx` environment, right?
- Automatically replace `\end{mytabularx}` with

  ```
  \bottomrule \end{tabularx}
  ```

  i.e., prefix the missing `\bottomrule` instruction to `\end{tabularx}`. That is the objective mentioned in the first sentence of your posting, but it's not the only objective, is it?

I would add a third item to this to-do list:

- Automatically prefix `\noindent` to `\begin{mytabularx}`. This is definitely necessary *unless* the length parameter `\parindent` has been set to zero.

---

If you are willing and able to use LuaLaTeX, you may achieve your formatting objectives by (a) setting up a Lua function -- called `mytabularx` in the code below -- which makes use of Lua's `gsub` function to perform the required string substitution operations and (b) asssigning this function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, to make it act as a pre-processor on your LaTeX code. That way, the Lua function gets to operate on the LaTeX code *before* TeX starts any of its own processing (such as macro expansion, etc.). Thus, LaTeX never gets to "see" an environment called `mytabularx`; instead, it gets to work on a well-appointed `tabularx` environment.

The code below provides a Lua function called `mytabularx` and two LaTeX helper macros, called `\mytabularxOn` and `\mytabularxOff`. (You're free to come up with different names...) The first macro activates the `mytabularx` function, i.e., assigns it to the `process_input_buffer` callback, and the second macro deactivates it.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,lipsum,luacode}

%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function mytabularx ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( '\\begin%s-{mytabularx}%s-(%b{})' , 
               '\\noindent\\begin{tabularx}{\\textwidth}%1\\toprule' ) 
  s = s:gsub ( '\\end%s-{mytabularx}' ,
               '\\bottomrule\\end{tabularx}' )
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: Macros to activate and deactivate the Lua function.
\newcommand\mytabularxOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   'process_input_buffer' , mytabularx , 'mytabularx' )}}
\newcommand\mytabularxOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
   'process_input_buffer' , 'mytabularx' )}}
\mytabularxOn % activate the Lua function by default

\begin{document}

% first, a tabularx environment without \toprule and \bottomrule:
\begin {tabularx} {\textwidth} {lcrX}
  this & is & my & \lipsum[1][1-5] \\ 
% Note that material spills into the right-hand margin
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}
 
% second, the 'mytabularx' environment
\begin {mytabularx} {lcrX}  
  this & is & my & \lipsum[1][1-4] \\
\end{mytabularx}

\end{document}
```